# Switching circuit with logic 3.3V control on p-channel JFET

Tags: high-frequency, modulation, jfet, small-signal, analog-switch

The task is to derive sinewave (of higher frequency) chopped by step-function (also periodic but of lower frequency, i.e. several periods of sine wave are placed in that pulse). So I have a sinewave generator with frequencies up to 50 MHz, I have 3.2-3.3V logic levels from my STM32 with the desired duty cycle and I need to deliver 0.5 V amplitude sine wave with 1 V DC offset for my 50 Ohm load connected to the ground (i.e. cannot be placed above the drain).
I hardly imagine how to deliver that sine pulse directly, so suppose we have a voltage buffer (with lil amplification) for the output. Also, it looks to me simpler to use JFET among other FETs because it's symmetric in drain and source. So far I only considered depletion mode P-channels, since it looked as winning solution having in general 0V Vgs as fully open and 3V Vgs as pinched-off. I've looked through a lot of models and analysis textbooks but yet cannot find the answer to the problem of having this 1 DC offset which appears on the drain as soon as the channel is fully open, i.e. can it burn the JFET and will it affect it's closing time and efficiency? If I added 1V DC bias to the gate terminal, would it be a solution or do I need some feedback from the drain? I don't see a case when it closes and opens completely.
Please have a look at the figures below. I indicated Vgs of established ON and OFF states, however, I suppose transient process should be taken as well, especially time constants of formed RC-circuits, but I have no complete understanding of what MUST be calculated and what's the priority.

[image: Test circuit and desired output diagram]

Currently, I can not manage even with this part, however, high-frequency effects should be included into the problem solution and if you have a piece of advice for that as well, you'd be helpful and I'd be enormously grateful.

Comment: I strongly urge you to use a simulator to develop your circuit.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps for the sake of explanation I find it not more helpful, besides the question is about analysis by hand. I have simulations and they are not satisfying.

Comment: The golden rule with simulations is that if they say something won't work then, almost certainly, the real thing won't work. Your question doesn't mention analysis by hand.

Comment: JFETs are almost never the simplest option. There are rarely some uses for them, but enhancement-mode devices are usually easier to use, and no one makes enhancement-mode JFETs for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple circuit made with discretes isn't going to work well. In the past, I used to do things like this using a tranconductance->differential pair->transimpedance topology. Fortunately, it's a lot easier these days: there are excellent low voltage wide bandwidth analog switch ICs available. Have a look at the [ADG701](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG701_702.pdf) to get started. Not a product recommendation: there are many similar parts available, and you'll have to choose the best for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for a simple solution, it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to go with a series/shunt switch configuration if you want much on/off ratio or at least reduce the 1M to more like 50Ω (more than 4 orders of magnitude!). Calculate how much the capacitive reactance is of your 'off' FET if you want to do hand calculations.

50MHz is a relatively high frequency. You might be able to get away with something like a DG419 SPST analog switch.

There are much higher performance (GHz) RF switch ICs available but they typically have issues with DC and are designed for lower voltage systems.

Comment: DG419 is an old high voltage switch, but this is a low voltage problem. There are higher performance low voltage CMOS switches that work fine down to DC.

Comment: @JohnDoty I was referring to the newer GHz GaAs and Silicon-Germanium technology switches that are used in wireless kit. They usually require coupling capacitors. Eg.  Skyworks.

Comment: Yes, I know. The are unsuitable here. But there are others that are suitable, with specs for switching 100's of MHz.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! If you're talking about 1MOhm at drain and approximate time constant formed with Cgd then I should mention this restriction is done to deliver the whole magnitude of the signal to the buffer. Having 50 Ohms there would result in at least 3 times less magnitude.

Comment: @Sombercy Yes, the problem is that it won't attenuate much when off. I imagine you are seeing that in simulation.